# Sending parameter from Html.DropDownList not completing redirect action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.dropdownlistfor, html-select

I am struggling to get the value out of this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ClientId, new SelectList(Model.Clients, "ClientId", "Name"))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientId)
```

So that I can submit it to this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveInvoice(Parameter from DropDownList)
{
//code code code etc
return RedirectToAction("Complete", new { id = invoice.InvoiceId });
}
```

My problem is, that using JQuery to run the post simply executes the SaveInvoice method with the parameter, the redirect does not happen. That redirect is extremely important. I believe I am making a mistake somewhere with my submitting form code (as this is using Html.BeginForm() ) but basically how do I get the value from that dropdownlist into my controller and run the controller method with the redirect as normal, and what variable type should I be using for my parameter? My viewmodel is strongly typed to called InvoiceViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't completely clear, but, if you're using an Ajax request to submit the form then your redirect isn't going to work without setting up additional Javascript to be aware of the HTTP 302/301 redirect.

If you're not using Ajax, then you should change your ActionResult to use the same object type as your using in your view:

```
public ActionResult SaveInvoice(ObjectType whateverNameYouWant) { ... }
```

ASP.NET MVC will automatically take care of doing the binding of the data in the POST to the object type.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, but I am attempting to avoid using ajax and jquery and use the tools that ASP.NET MVC provides. Using JQuery etc kind of circumvents the point of MVC and html helpers.